# Yoast SEO creates sitemaps with a dash '-' but I can't get Bing to accept them

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, search-engines, sitemap

I've submitted my sitemaps to Google, Ask, and yahoo with no problems but when I try to submit to Bing on 3 different computers PC and Macs Bing rejects without any warning all sitemaps with a dash. post-sitemap.xml for example won't be added. If I remove the dash it allows me to add it. (but of course that does me no good.)

Comment: Are you sure the dash is the issue? I highly doubt that it's that, I think it's actually the fact that there's images in there...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not an issue at all, it works just like it's supposed to, be sure to submit the index sitemap though, not the individual ones, so submit `sitemap_index.xml`.

See this screenshot for reference to show that it works:

[image: Bing Webmaster Tools]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have submitted that several times and it returns errors once crawled.  sitemap_index.xml Errors found Unknown type 0 urls submitted. Any other suggestions?